# error: Command not found, on sending command line arguments

Tags: c, linux

I have a very simple program below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("\n %s",argv[3]);
}
```

Say the executable is named a.out and running it as $./a.out open path/to/my/file O_WRONLY|O_APPEND 
 gives  Command no found error.
where as running it as running it as $./a.out open path/to/my/file O_WRONLY
gives output O_WRONLY.

Is it because of |

Thanks for you valuable time.

Comment: Escape it like this: `./a.out open path/to/my/file O_WRONLY\|O_APPEND` or even try like this: `./a.out open path/to/my/file O_WRONLY'|'O_APPEND`

Answer (score 2):

Your shell takes the `|` before `O_APPEND` as a pipe, and doesn't recognize this command (because it doesn't exist) try  `$./a.out open path/to/my/file "O_WRONLY|O_APPEND"`.

Also, don't use `void main`, use `int main` (some people here might get a heart attack if they see it :) )

Comment: Thanks...:-)(yeah I guess void main will give a heart attack to many C-orthodoxians)\

Answer (score 2):

The pipe character `|` has a special meaning to the shell: it creates a *pipeline*, where the output of one process is piped into the input of another process.  When you type `foo | bar`, the shell spawns the two processes with command lines of `foo` and `bar` and connects the output of the former to the input of the latter.

To avoid this behavior, put quotes around your command line arguments:

```
$ ./a.out open path/to/my/file "O_WRONLY|O_APPEND"
```